# Crashed app after change the package name

Tags: android

I try to change the package name.First, I rename package that is src folder, then select rename package name in android tools menu.Now when run the app: crashed the app. 
Logcat errors :

```
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nabproduct.nabege/com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.nabproduct.nabege.DB_Nabege_helper.count_collection(DB_Nabege_helper.java:156)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity.fill_listView(Collection_List_Activity.java:361)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.nabproduct.nabege.Collection_List_Activity.onCreate(Collection_List_Activity.java:199)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-15 15:35:19.747: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Comment: What are you doing in `com.nabproduct.nabege.DB_Nabege_helper.count_collection(DB_Nabege_helper.java:156)`?

Comment: two quick suggestions - clean/rebuild and restart your IDE - sometimes these will fix this type of error

Comment: I execute the query on the database and get records count   of table collection .

Comment: I clean/rebuild and restart my IDE, but don't solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the database path with a string like this: "/data/data/com.example. nabege/databases/". I changed  it and solved the problem.Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of thing you should change. have you changed the application ID in the gradle file??? it doesn't change automatically. have you updated the android manifest file?
try considering there...

Comment: I work in eclipse .When change package  name , manifest file changed automatically